# Dynamic stageWidth and Height in Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, web-applications, stage

This seems like it would be a really easy thing to do, but its been giving me all kinds of headaches.  I have a movieclip that is a gallery, It's linked to be called from AS when a button is clicked.  When an image in the gallery is clicked, It fades in using the Tween class and is *supposed* to be centered in the main stage, but its centering to the movieClip instead.

Here is the code:

```
//Centers and places image right ondo the display board
function fullLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var myFull:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
    addChild(myFull);

    //positioning
    myFull.x = (stage.stageWidth - myFull.width) / 2;
    myFull.y = (stage.stageHeight - myFull.height) /2;

    //register the remove function
    myFull.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeFull);

    new Tween(myFull, "alpha", Strong.easeInOut,0,1,0.5,true);
}
```

I have tried all of these combinations to no avail:

```
MovieClip(root).stage.stageWidth  
root.stage.stageWidth  
parent.stage.stageWidth
```

None of these place the image in the right spot.

Comment: Hi,

Have you checked the `stage.align` propertie ?

Comment: Yea, I've tried that too, without success :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set these this property to make your stage have it's origo (0x0) in the top left:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

And this to make the stage stay the same scale as the window changes size:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Then you will need to wait until your image is loaded before you align it, since it won't have a width before then.  I would also recommend listening for `Event.RESIZE` on the stage, this is fired whenever the size changes.

Assuming all that your current code should work fine!

```
myFull.x = (stage.stageWidth - myFull.width) / 2;
myFull.y = (stage.stageHeight - myFull.height) /2;
```

Comment: It doesnt work though, because that returns the size of the containing movieclip, not the main stage! :(

Comment: stage.stageWidth gives the stages width i'm sure of it. 
If you're getting strange values try adding the listeners.

Comment: also, the myFull position is obviously related to whatever the x position it parent has.

Answer (score 0):

`MovieClip(root).addChild(myFull);`
don't forget to do the same to `removeChild`